# Specify element ID in Ruby on Rails submit button form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to apply an ID attribute to the form's submit button using the following code:

```
= form_for @guild do |f|
  = f.file_field :image
  = f.text_area :description
  = f.submit "speichern", id: "message_button"
```

Here is the generated HTML:

```
<form class="new_message" id="new_message" action="#" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="..." />      
  <input type="hidden" name="chat_room_id" id="chat_room_id" value="2" />
  <div class='form-group'>
    <textarea class="text-area" name="message[body]" id="message_body">
    </textarea>
    <small class='text-muted'>From 2 to 1000 characters</small>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Post" data-disable-with="Post" />
</form>
```

But when I look at the generated HTML, there is no ID.
How can I add an ID to this element?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice where you want add id attribute. This code should work fine. Did you check generated code in source view? Not in devtools. Do you have some kind of caching enabled?

Comment: it's the same in source view

Comment: The above should work. Is your application running in production mode? If so, you'll need to restart it to see the change.

Comment: @pdoherty926 a restart didn't help either

Comment: As @MichałMłoźniak suggested, it sounds like something is being cached. You should try opening a new tab in incognito mode or using a new browser. Also, you should include the source code of the relevant section of the generated HTML.

Comment: @pdoherty926 It's the same in incognito mode

Comment: It appears that this form is being generated by different code - the image and description fields aren't present in the output and your code snippet wouldn't be generating a `div.form-group`. Perhaps you're making changes to edit.haml instead of new.haml?

Comment: @pdoherty926 Yes, thank you, that was the issue. Why didn't I see that?

Comment: Great. I'll submit a proper answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the HAML snippet you've included *should* be creating a submit button with the desired ID.

Secondly, it appears that the HTML you've included is being generated by some different code: the image and description fields aren't present in the provided HTML and your code snippet wouldn't be generating a `div.form-group`. Perhaps you're making changes to edit.haml instead of new.haml?